# What am I doing wrong with this javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want this simple javascript to display live data from the Cryptsy market. In the fiddle, it works fine, but when I deploy it live, it does not display. I'm new to javascript and coding-beyond-html in general, so I'll greatly appreciate any help!

Deployed: http://bytillionaire.com/HTMLCoin.com/index.html

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bitillionaire/5fub4mvf/2/

code here:

```
    <head>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function() {
      $(function() {
        startRefresh();
      });

      function startRefresh() {
        setTimeout(startRefresh, 10000);
        var url = 'http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=458';
        $.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '%22&format=json', function(data) {
          jQuery('#ticker').html(data['query'].results.json.return.markets.HTML5.lasttradeprice);
          jQuery('#ticker').append(' ' + data['query'].results.json.return.markets.HTML5.secondarycode);
        });
      }
    }); //]]>
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="navigation">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/htmlcoin" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @htmlcoin</a>
    <script>
      ! function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
          js = d.createElement(s);
          js.id = id;
          js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
      }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
    </script>
    <div id="ticker"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Look in your console. `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined `. You are probably trying to run some JQuery code before jquery has loaded

Comment: Or maybe I'm so stupid that I'm not even calling jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I see an error at your site in console  `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
it looks like jQuery is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included jQuery on your page!

Answer (score 0):

You dont have `jQuery` in your webpage.

Add this in the  of your HTML code and it should be before other scripts:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to always have a copy of jquery.js in your javascript folder and to call it!

In

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

This will ensure that jquery functions are able to run.